# Как сравнить две коллекции по значению в объектах, игнорируя некоторые из них

Tags: c#

Сигнатура должна быть следующей

```
public static void CompareCollections<T>(IEnumerable<T> expected, IEnumerable<T> actual, IEnumerable<string>? excludeProps = null)
```

Как сделать дальше идей вообще нет

Comment: Сравнивать можно по-разному. Приведите пример прямо в вопросе, что на входе и что на выходе. И лучше всё-таки распишите подробнее по какому принципу должно быть сравнение. Каждый с каждым или параллельно или как вообще. Кстати, сигнатура метода у вас `void`, это значит, что результат вам вообще не нужен?

Comment: Выражение туда добавьте еще, и будет у вас как LINQ `CompareCollections(..., ..., ..., x=>x.Property ...)`